# Why is this method getting a Null pointer Exception?

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist, android-sqlite, android-spinner

I am new to android but this is a simple task. I am trying to get a list of names from SQLite table in order set up a spinner that will let the user choose between those names. But for some reason Eclipse says that I have a null pointer exception. Why? I test often during development so I know that this brand new code is the cause of the error. Help please..

This is the method that sets up my spinner

```
private void setUpSpin() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ProjDbUI namer = new ProjDbUI(Projects.this);
    if(namer.getProjects() != null){
    projNames = namer.getProjects();
    }else{
        Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
        d.setTitle("Null name array!");
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("FAilure");
        d.setContentView(tv);
        d.show();
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Projects.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, projNames);
    spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spProjectChoise);
    spin.setAdapter(adapter);
    spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

And this is my method from ProjDbUI that has to be causing the issue:

```
public String[] getProjects() {
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_HOTNESS};
    ArrayList<String> projNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor c = myDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    if(c != null){
        int i = 0;
        for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        if(!projNames.contains(c.getString(1))) 
            projNames.add(c.getString(1));
        }

    }
    String[] reString = new String[projNames.size()];
    for(int i = 0;i < projNames.size();i++){
        reString[i] = projNames.get(i);
    }
    return reString;
}
```

Any ideas?

If I print `Thread.currentThread.getStackTrace()` I get:
[Ljava.lang.StackTrace,@45fe09c8
If I print the thrown exception`.toString()` I get:
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Posting the stack trace will help other answer your question.

Comment: Just a small comment on your code. You should remember to call c.close() before returning in your getProjects() method.

Comment: I'm noticing you don't use the variable `i` declared above your first for loop.  It seems the error might be at `c.getString(1)`.

Comment: Hmm .. cannot see how getProjects() should ever return null as it should if anything return an empty array as I see it.

Comment: @PaulDraper: Are these stackTrace printout what you asked for?

Comment: @MattLogan: I am using an existing table with 3 columns. Should referencing the 2nd column (c.getString(1)) give me an error? and yes I was moving to fast and for got to remove that random int i = 0.

Comment: How do you initialise `myDatabase` variable? Maybe it is null?

Comment: Set some breakpoints and debug it.